# Allow Helper Services to Only be Called From One Service in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following structure:

```
PdfGenerationService (umbrella)
    PdfGenerationDataService (gets data for umbrella)
    PdfGenerationFunctionService (calls Azure function "microservice" to gen PDF)
    PdfAzureSaveService (saves PDF to storage)
```

The problem is that other devs and myself have the tendency to try to use one of the "supporting" services outside of the "umbrella" service, when they really have no stand-alone functionality. We remember this too late, and by the time we do, we need to refactor.

e.g. we call the supporting `PdfAzureSaveService` from a controller, and then remember that we have the `PdfGenerationService` that does all of this for us without getting into the details and need to refactor.

I want to limit the helper services to only be usable within the umbrella `PdfGenerationService`. Access levels don't seem to help me with that, unless I want to make an arbitrary parent class that all 4 inherit from and then make the helper services `protected`. The other alternative is to put all the helpers into private methods on the "umbrella" service, that really violates DRY imo.

**tl;dr:** Is there some way to mark methods as only accessible from one service?

edit: JHBonarius made a good point that I should mention - these services ARE exposed via standard .NET Core DI. There is no real reason that they couldn't be static (and avoiding DI entirely), but that seems to still leave the problem of other services/controllers just importing the namespace and using the static services where they shouldn't.

Comment: I think you mean you only want dependency injection to expose certain services to certain other services... well this simplest way is just not to use DI: create local objects. And if you don't want other classes or namespaces to see eachother, make them `internal` or `private`. (and TBH, if your developers keep using the wrong service, then there might be something wrong with your architecture, or you need more communication.)

Comment: @JhBonarius That is definitely a better way to phrase what I am asking. I think there are two concerns with that - one is that DI is convenient and "in-line with out patterns", even if everything is just being DIed into `PdfGenerationService`. The second problem is that I don't want to have them in the same file for sake of keeping the file short, like I mentioned. If I make them separate services / classes, even static, in their own namespace, we can still use them in other places accidentally, as there is nothing to indicate that they are exclusive to the `PdfGenerationService `.

Comment: I would personally even go as far as putting the whole set in a `PdfGenerator` project with it's own servicebuilder extention `AddPdfGenerator` and only exposing a `IPdgGeneratorService`... that's my way of Clean Architecture.

Comment: `and TBH, if your developers keep using the wrong service` - I wrote the service and I am using it incorrectly after about a year of not touching it. I am reflecting on why I am using it incorrectly, and the gist is that I simply forgot to check for an umbrella that helps me with other stuff, and then saw it later. Maybe I am looking for a code solution to a situation where I should have checked the code more. I just like these things to be "intuitive" for new developers that come into the project.

Comment: I will look into doing the last thing you recommended - I have done it on other projects, but it was often overkill. Seems like it's something I should seriously consider here. Ty for the discussion, helped me think through this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your scenario is that you have a class which requires three other classes:

```
public PdfGenerationService(
    PdfGenerationDataService s1, 
    PdfGenerationFunctionService s2,
    PdfAzureSaveService s3
)
```

And you register those classes with DI:

```
services.AddTransient<PdfGenerationService>();
services.AddTransient<PdfGenerationDataService>();
services.AddTransient<PdfGenerationFunctionService>();
services.AddTransient<PdfAzureSaveService>();
```

And now you want to prevent developers from writing, in their own code:

```
public Foo(PdfGenerationFunctionService s1)
```

Because they're supposed to use `PdfGenerationService` as a dependency?

Then move all those classes into their own library, and make the three dependencies of the first service `internal`. Now other code can't refer to them by their name, so it can't ask for them to be injected.

Or write an analyzer that checks that other code doesn't use those classes. Or mark them obsolete, suppressing the warning in `PdfGenerationService`'s constructor. Or throw an exception in the three other class's methods if the method one stack frame lower doesn't originate from  `PdfGenerationService` (but don't).

Comment: I think a separate class library and `internal` is what I am really after here. Moving this to a class library project seemed kind of like overkill, but in reality it puts a nice boundry on all of this.